# Convert Sphere UV Coordinates to Object Coordinates

Tags: uv, displacement, coordinates, procedural, conversion

I am trying to procedurally flatten out roughly one half of a sphere by using displacement. This would be easy to do by using Object or Texture Coordinates, but since I need these to be preserved for later steps, meaning every vertex keeps its original coordinates, I need to use UV Coordinates. Do you have any ideas how I can convert the UV Coordinates for a spehere generated by Blender to the initial Object Coordinates I would get without any displacement? The result should look roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason not to be using Shape Keys for this?

Comment: Shape Keys are not supported by other applications I am using and I find them rather inconvinient. Thanks for the suggestion, though, I might look into this more, if I can't find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it seems I managed to get the Z-Coordinate by utilizing some of the formulars for circle segment calculation that I learned in school but have gone lost like many things. Here is the Node Tree, if anyone is interested:
[image]